# MongoDB - Permission denied for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Tags: sockets, mongodb, file-permissions, upstart

I had an unclean shutdown of MongoDB on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Now when I login as root and run Mongodb via service mongodb start, I get below error-

```
Mon Dec 12 13:53:15 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:13 Permission denied for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

When I run MongoDB manually via root, it works just fine.

I can confirm that there is no /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock file

```
root@devbox:~# ll /tmp/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2011-12-12 13:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 2011-12-11 13:06 ../
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 2011-12-12 13:01 .ICE-unix/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 2011-12-12 13:01 .X11-unix/
```

Where do I begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What's are the file permissions on /tmp? Is it possible that they've been changed?

A

```
# ls -ld /tmp
```

will tell you.

If you're unsure try:

```
# chown root:root /tmp
# chmod 1777 /tmp
```

That might fix it.

Comment: You are right, after unclean shutdown, thins got messed up and /tmp was not write-able anymore by MongoDb user.

Comment: Great. Glad we found you an answer.

Comment: You save my day. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent. Glad to help.

Answer (score 20):

Try changing owner like this,

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: This fixed my issue ! Thanks

Comment: Thank god it finally worked!! Thanks! It's weird because `/tmp` had `rwx` permission for all three yet the operation was not permitted until I tried your example.

Comment: It seems when using Debian based systems the user is mongodb, but when using Centos systems the user id mongod (notice no 'b' in the user name).  Be careful out there!

Comment: this fixed my issue | Thanks

Answer (score 5):

we use mac and install mongodb,
usually do not need mongodb.conf,
so, try this:

```
sudo chown -R your-username /tmp/
```

ps:your-username is your username in mac os, not root.if you don't know what is your username,there's a command:

```
whoami
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Versions before 3.0 the socket was created with 777 permissions by default.
Most the most correct way set permissions to mongod socket is set value in **mongodb.conf**. For example:

```
sudo vim /usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf
```

and insert line:

```
filePermissions = 0777
```

to it.

In case if you will try directly change permissions to **/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock** with **chown** and **chmod** you can have a chance set it temporary. And have a old permissions after mongod service restart or server reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Ubuntu mongo user has access to the file.  The Mongo Ubuntu service uses the Ubuntu Mongo user.  To find out the mongo username is go to /var/lib/mongodb directory and show the permissions: ls -l

Comment: `root@devbox:~# ls -l  /var/lib/mongodb
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 2011-12-12 13:53 journal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb    0 2011-12-12 13:53 mongod.lock`

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, because I have use run mongodb by root, it will start fail with `systemctl` on CentOS 7.3.

Please use the correct permission for mongodb.

`$ sudo chown -R mongod:mongod \
      /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid \
      /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock \
      /var/lib/mongo/`

If we have other fail like `Error reading file /path/file: Permission denied`, maybe we can fix it by **SELinux**.

`$ sudo chcon -v -t mongod_var_lib_t /path/file`

By the way, I don't recomment use the 777 permission, it's so danger. :P