# 'Failed to unlink socket file" error in MongoDB 3.0

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-13.04

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to install MongoDb 3.0 on Ubuntu 13.0 LTS, which is a VM on Windows 7 Host. I have installed MongoDB successfully (packages etc.), but when I execute the command `sudo service mongod start`, I get the following error in the "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" log file. Can anyone help me understanding this error. There is nothing on internet related to this.

> 2015-04-23T00:12:00.876-0400 I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
>   2015-04-23T00:12:00.931-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket **file /tmp/mongodb-27017.soc**k errno:1 Operation not permitted
>   2015-04-23T00:12:00.931-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
>   2015-04-23T00:12:00.931-0400 I -        [initandlisten]

Comment: This is a question better suited for DBA StackExchange, but hopefully it should be moved there by moderators :). Can you include the output of  `ls -lat /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`? I suspect you may have started `mongod` as a different user (perhaps root) rather than starting with the service (which should use the `mongodb` user). You should be able to fix this by stopping the `mongod` service, `sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`, and then starting the service again. The error here is fairly benign, unless you want to connect to `mongod` over a domain socket instead of via a TCP/IP connection.

Comment: I have fixed this issue myself, by deleting the 'mongodb-27017.sock' file . I ran the service after deleting this file, which worked fine. However, I am still not sure the root cause of the issue.  The output of the command 'ls - lat /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock' is 'srwx------ 1 mongodb nogroup 0 Apr 23 06:24 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38843534/1773972 They suggested changing permission of that file, and it tested on ubuntu 16.04 and worked for me !

Answer (score 177, accepted):

I have fixed this issue myself, by deleting the `mongodb-27017.sock` file . I ran the service after deleting this file, which worked fine. However, I am still not sure the root cause of the issue. The output of the command `ls - lat /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` is now

```
srwx------ 1 mongodb nogroup 0 Apr 23 06:24 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

**The best option is not to delete the lock file**

Instead,  check the file user and group user. Set both to the current user:

- First run: `whoami`
- Then run: `sudo chown <output of the above command> /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`
- Next run: `sudo service mongod restart && sudo mongod`

Comment: This works for me temporarily, but it seems the file gets recreated automatically. Has anyone found a long term fix for this issue? On Ubuntu 14.04 server edition.

Comment: will this commend delete my dbs

Comment: Although this works, isn't it also because the SELinux was enforced on the VM?

Comment: In addition u have to kill every mongo process running.

Comment: i also tried doing this but i need to perform this action everytime.

Comment: I disabled SELinux which I dont need, then I changed owner of file to mongod
"chown mongod:mongod mongodb-27017.sock"
this worked for me, even if I reboot server, mongo starts without problem

Comment: i had to remove and install mongo multiple times finally i remove the .sock file and it worked thanks a lot !!

Comment: thank you so much!!! finally my 4 hours of debugging seem to be coming to an end

Comment: I do not understand why you're recommending mongod br run twice!
That recommendation CAUSES the issue!  ALWAYS use service (or systemctl) to launch mongod for you...

`sudo service mongod stop && 
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock &&
sudo service mongod start`

Comment: If you're running mongo via systemd, rather than set the user to output of whoami, check the systemd's service unit for the correct user and group.  You can likely find it here: /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service.  Check User and Group directives, then chown the /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock to that user and group using sudo.

Answer (score 59):

Alternative to the answer provided by KurioZ7, you can simply set the permissions of the .sock file to the current user:

```
sudo chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

This does the trick for me if I want to run mongod without sudo. If I delete the file like in KurioZ7s answer, I will simply get the same error the next time I restart my machine.

Comment: This is the better answer compared to the one by @KurioZ7 as this provides a permanent fix!

Answer (score 42):

This issue occurs when you use the command

```
mongod
```

Before using the command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

To fix the issue, either:

Set appropriate permissions on the file:

```
/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

OR

Remove the file

```
/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Run

```
sudo service mongod start && mongod
```

Comment: What are the appropriate permissions? Who should the owner and group be?

Comment: You saved my day, Greg Miller.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the cause of the creation of this file

Answer (score 12):

The most likely cause for this was that the mongod process was at some point started by the root user. The socket file (/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock) was therefore owned by the root user. The mongod process usually runs under its own dedicated user, and that user did not have the permissions to delete that file.

The solution, as you already found out, was to delete it. Then mongodb was able to recreate it with the correct permissions. This should persist after reboot, as long as mongodb is started using the init scripts, or under the correct user account.

Answer (score 12):

Change the ownership mongodb-27017.sock file in /tmp directory and start the mongod again.

```sh
cd /tmp
```

```sh
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb mongodb-27017.sock
```

```sh
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Comment: Mongo logs was showing me "aborting after fassert() failure"  and service was not started so I tried this solution and it worked.

Comment: This worked!! I had to purge, reinstall, rerun and then do this, but now we're good!!

Answer (score 11):

```
$ sudo mongod
```

it solve problem for me

Answer (score 3):

For UNIX-based operating systems, as an alternative to the answer provided by Bastronaut, you could also specify the .sock file to be saved to a folder over which mongod has full user rights (corresponding to the way you are running mongod), that way mongod will also be able to remove the .sock file upon shutdown. The default folder to which the .sock file is saved is '/tmp'. To specify another folder, use a custom mongodb configuration file, for instance 'mongodb.conf', and add the following to it:

```
net:
  unixDomainSocket:
    pathPrefix: "anotherFolder"
```

After which you can run mongod with the command:

```
$ mongod --config /path/to/mongodb.conf
```

You can read the documentation on: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.unixDomainSocket.pathPrefix

Answer (score 2):

For permanent fix, please set user to `root` in `mongod.service` file:

1. Edit service file:
   `systemctl edit mongod.service`.
2. Type in content:

```bash
[Service]
User=root
```

3. `ctrl+o` + `ennter` to save, `ctrl+x` to exit editing.
4. restart mongo database: `systemctl restart mongod`

Answer (score 1):

Manually restarting mongod service after restart fixed the problem.

**Long-term solution** was to add static host name, instead of ip address 'net' part of  mongod.conf file (I suspect the problem is that ip address is not yet given to server, when mongod servis starts).

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem using docker, refer to this question:

[MongoDB docker container “Failed to unlink socket file”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871498/mongodb-docker-container-failed-to-unlink-socket-file)