# Failed to start mongod.service on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, nosql, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed Mongodb on Ubuntu but can not **start** it,I'm really stuck  at this point! I've tried lots of solutions but none of them worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated

when I run start command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

It says:

```
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with 

error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And output of status command is:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod.service
```

> ● mongod.service
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: **failed** (Result: exit-code) since جمعه 2018-03-30 15:00:56 +0430; 2s ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
>     **Process: 5500 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**
>
> 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC mongod[5500]: Rather than invoking
>   init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC mongod[5500]: utility, e.g.
>   service mongod start مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC
>   mongod[5500]: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect
>   to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart:
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC mongod[5500]: Since the
>   script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC mongod[5500]: Upstart job,
>   you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongod
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC mongod[5500]: start: Unable
>   to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket
>   /com/ubuntu/upstart: Co
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mongod.service:
>   Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: **Failed to start
>   mongod.service.**
>
> مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mongod.service:
>   Unit entered failed state. مارس 30 15:00:56 mahdi-HP-15-Notebook-PC
>   systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010719/mongodb-not-able-to-start-in-ubuntu-15-04... it works for me

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Yes, I tried that, But did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced exactly the same problem. I followed the [official MongoDB community guide,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for installing MongoDB on a xubuntu 16.04 workstation. The service worked fine until I rebooted after installation.

Then the service stopped working and it displayed the behavior that you describe in your question. I noticed that after the first reboot the folder `/var/log/mongodb` disappeared. After manually creating it, I was able to run `mongod`, until the next reboot.

The solution to this problem is to change the file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`, in order to instruct systemd to create this folder and assign it to user `mongodb` just before loading `mongod` service. Just add the following lines in the `[Service]` section:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/
```

Then you should be able to start the sevice by using either
`sudo systemctl start mongod`
or
`sudo service mongod start`

Here are all the commands for performing the installation based on the official guide.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y mongodb-org

# this command performs the edit described above    
sudo sed -i 's/Group=mongodb/Group=mongodb\nExecStartPre=\/bin\/mkdir -p \/var\/log\/mongodb\/\nExecStartPre=\/bin\/chown -R mongodb:mongodb \/var\/log\/mongodb\//g' /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

# enable and run the service
sudo systemctl enable mongod
sudo systemctl start mongod

# run mongo client and check the service
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017
```

And here's how to **completely** remove MongoDB (incuding the logs and the **databases**):

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
```