# MongoDb doesn't start Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

when i write this command
`sudo service mongod start`

that giving me this error
`Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`
i search on the stackoverflow and found it [Mongodb not able to start in Ubuntu 15.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010719/mongodb-not-able-to-start-in-ubuntu-15-04)
but this doesn't work for me and this problem asked the 5 years ago
and when i write the this command
`sudo service mongod status`

giving me to

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-07-24 22:49:47 UTC; 3min 49s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 4126 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 4123 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4120 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4119 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal mongod[4126]: Error parsing YAML config: duplicate key: replication.rep...Name
Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal mongod[4126]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Jul 24 22:49:47 ip-172-31-46-146.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and this command
`sudo systemctl disable mongod`

giving me
`Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongod.service.`

and i doing the enable happen this
`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

`Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongod.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service.`

it's my mongod.conf file

```
  GNU nano 2.9.8                                                 /etc/mongod.conf                                                            

# mongod.conf# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
# network interfaces
net:  port: 34418
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.31.46.146  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll settin$

#security:
   #authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:
```

Comment: How your  /etc/mongod.conf look like?

Comment: i share only green content 
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 34418
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.31.46.146  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll settin$


security:
  authorization: "enabled"
@R2D2

Comment: you need to understand in the yaml where this is comming from: duplicate key: replication

Comment: when i disable authorization dis problem is solve but i have to use authorization @R2D2

Comment: add the full conf content so we check where is the issue, but it is definetely in the yaml

Comment: okey but i cant add this here cause max character is full how can i send you my conf and what is the yaml?

Comment: i added the my question you can check my conf file @R2D2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your conf file to enable simple authentication/authorization you need to do as follow:

1. start without authorization enabled( you said it is working without authorization) binded to 127.0.0.1 only  and create admin user and initialize the repicaSet if it is not initialized yet:

   ```
    mongo --port 34418

    db.createUser({user:"admin" ,pwd:"someStrongOne" ,roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin" }]})

    rs.initiate()
   ```
2. Stop the mongod service
3. Generate key file:

   ```
    mkdir /work/dbtest/key
    openssl rand -base64 756 > /work/dbtest/key
   ```
4. Change permission for the keyfile to be read only by the mongod user:

   ```
    chmod 400 /work/dbtest
   ```
5. Uncomment the authorization config and add the key file so it looks as follow:

   ```
   security:
    authorization: "enabled"
    keyFile: /work/dbtest/key
   ```
6. Start the mongod process
7. Now you can access as follow:

   ```
   mongo --port 34418 admin -u admin -p someStrongOne
   ```

btw in the pasted conf file there is some new lines that need to be added before "dbPath" and before "port" so it is valid yaml file ... , please, note proposed security configuration it is intended for testing purposes only , if you expose this service over network it is  strongly recommended you add transport encryption ( X.509 etc., this is well explained in the official mongodb docs )

Comment: Still i geting same error. at the 6 step ```Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.```

Comment: you can run and check  the mongod process from console as follow: mongod --config xxx.conf