# Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied

Tags: macos, mongodb, sockets, connection

When I try to start mongo db I get the following error:

```
Trying to run the command : ./mongod --dbpath=../data
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
Fatal Assertion 28578
```

As per the suggestions from other posts, have tried to locate the file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`, to delete. But the file itself is not available.

But when I tried to do it using root, I am able to start the mongo DB. For normal users it fails.

Version used: `mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Failed to unlink socket file" error in MongoDB 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0)

Answer (score 14):

Remove file

> /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
>
> /dbpath/mongod.lock

try start with any user not root user.

Comment: the file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock is not available. Tried by deleting the mongod.lock. But not working.

Comment: I also tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Current user does not have permissions to delete that file.

Grant permissions to the current user:

sudo chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Comment: I tried this and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

The following steps work for me:

```
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

sudo systemctl start mongod // wont start but will create .sock file again

sudo chown "[current user]" /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

sudo systemctl start mongod // will start now

sudo systemctl status mongod // should show active
```