# mongo errno:61 Connection refused on OSX Yosemite

Tags: mongodb

This has been asked before, but I can't seem to get this resolved for me from other answers.

I am getting the following error when trying to run `mongo` on OSX Yosemite:

> 2015-11-27T11:50:51.644+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
>   2015-11-27T11:50:51.645+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179

I installed via brew.

People have mentioned a /data/db directory (which I can't find) and removing a mongo.lock file (which I can't find either).

I can see mongo files located at /usr/local/bin, but no lock files.

Thank you

Comment: you have to create `/data/db` this folders and make it writable and readble

Comment: But doesn't Homebrew create it's own default location at `/usr/local/var/mongodb`? I have a mongodb directory at this location.

Comment: I didnt use Homebrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed on my mac *MongoDB* few days ago. You can follow for this ***[Link](http://www.choskim.me/how-to-install-mongodb-on-apples-mac-os-x/)*** and complete all steps. It's quite easy to install *MongoDB* on mac.

Additional information :

***[Link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)***, ***[Failed to unlink socket file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0)***

I hope it will help you.

Thanks!

Comment: it depends on what you did before)

Comment: Installed via Homebrew

Comment: @zeKoko `cd /data/db` and you will see if this path exists. This is folder where MongoDB store data. I've installed it manually

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled, followed the instructions in the Link above  and got the following error:
2015-11-27T12:20:30.458+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
2015-11-27T12:20:30.459+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2015-11-27T12:20:30.459+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: @zeKoko new [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0) how to solve this error

Comment: Ok, removed that and ran mongod and got a load of info, last 2 lines were: 2015-11-27T12:32:21.129+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.13 secs
2015-11-27T12:32:21.194+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017. Now there is just a blinking cursor.

Comment: Ran `mongo` and got: 2015-11-27T12:34:42.855+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-11-27T12:34:42.856+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179

Comment: Great, you've run a mongodb server. Now you can connect to it through any api or iterm just tipe `mongo'

Comment: `mongo` doesn't work, give me the following error:
2015-11-27T12:36:05.697+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-11-27T12:36:05.699+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96355/discussion-between-naz-and-zekoko).