# MongoDB Failing to Start - ***aborting after fassert() failure

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, startup

I am new to Ubuntu (Linux tbh). I encountered problem with starting MongoDB service. I want to created web app using Ruby on Rails and MongoDB but mongo seems to fail to start.

I followed this [MongoDB installation on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) all of installation went without problems until I got to `sudo service mongod start`

**mongod.log**

```
2016-01-01T10:58:15.545+0000 I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-01-01T10:58:15.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3868 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=damian-CX61-0NC-CX61-0ND-CX61-0NF-CX61-0NE
2016-01-01T10:58:15.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.8
2016-01-01T10:58:15.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 83d8cc25e00e42856924d84e220fbe4a839e605d
2016-01-01T10:58:15.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-187-89-126 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-01-01T10:58:15.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-01T10:58:15.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-01-01T10:58:15.567+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2016-01-01T10:58:15.567+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2016-01-01T10:58:15.567+0000 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

So what I am doing wrong or its different issue?

Comment: Does the file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock exist? If so try to delete it, ie. 'sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock'.

Comment: @kometen I think that worked - how to check that mongo is actually running? Like in windows I had cmd window with all these things going on - here I cant see any of it. Is mongod.log the only way to know what is going on?

Comment: `ps ax | grep [m]ongod`

Comment: I also think there is a 'service mongodb status'.

Comment: 2520 ?        Sl     0:09 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x /bin/sh -c cd '/home/damian/Downloads/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.2.0/bin' && exec $SHELL
 3751 ?        Sl     0:06 gedit /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
 4020 ?        Ssl    0:23 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
 4206 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mongo

What does this mean? Am I running 4 different mongodb's at the same time?

Comment: I'm not shure where the output came from. But there are probably more than one process to handle the requests.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

SOLUTION by [kometen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319826/kometen)

> Does the file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock exist? If so try to delete it, ie. 'sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock'.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: I'm using Mac (Sierra OS), but I can't find this file... thanks @fresz

Comment: Hey guys, this solution is for linux. What this do its removing temporary file which didnt delete itself and its blocking normal operation.

Comment: Hey guys this solution doesn't work for me. When I delete mongod-27017.sock and try to start mongod, the file pops back up in /tmp. Suggestions?

Comment: @larry are u on Linux? Does your service for mongodb start at all?

Comment: Yes I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I was able to resolve my issue by installing version 4.0.10. Turns out version 4.0.9 and 4.0.11 have compatibility issues with Ubuntu.

Comment: I also had an issue with this file reappearing in /tmp. I think for me it was because I had a running mongodb-runner process. I killed it, and `sudo service mongod start` behaved as expected.

Answer (score 8):

The problem can also be due to mongodb using up all the disk space. That was the case for me. You can install ncdu with this command:
**sudo apt install ncdu**

This will help you in looking at the disk usage. Use the command:
**ncdu -x /**

Remove the unwanted dbs from **/var/lib/mongodb/**

Comment: Thanks. That memory thing issue reminded me and saved my day

Comment: `ncdu` is not for memory, it's for disk space, huge difference.

Comment: @Moshe Thanks for pointing it out, updated the solution

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo mongod
```

(suggested by @João Bortolosso)

after (suggested by @fresz):

```
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

worked on mac!

Answer (score 6):

If you use Ubuntu, try:

```sh
sudo mongod
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because of the bad data inside the folder: ‘/data/db’

**Solution that worked for me:** Remove all the files inside '/data/db'

Answer (score 2):

We was getting the same message in Production and service was not restarted

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-18T15:18:27.834+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

So I ran this command (Giving the permission to mongodb user)

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb mongodb-27017.sock
```

And started the service

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Now mongo is up and running. ;)

[Credit Goes to our StackOverflow Contributor Rajith K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692300/7300865)

He gave the answer on **'Failed to unlink socket file" error in MongoDB 3.0**

Answer (score 1):

```
mongo --shell
```

It worked for me on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete MongoDB temp file

```
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

for any one getting this error after every restart, u need to stop mongod.service on startup

```
sudo systemctl disable mongod.service
```

the name `mongod.service` may change later, so just write mongo and press tab for autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

clear the files inside **c:\data\db** folder and then start mongodb database using **mongod** command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).