# MongoDB aborting after fassert() failure, mongod --repair doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I just reinstalled OSX from a backup and now I can't get mongod to work. I'm getting the `***aborting after fassert() failure` error. Here's a pastebin with the log: http://pastebin.com/5WmXdGKd.

I get the same error if I try to run `sudo mongod --repair`. I also tried the solution offered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946049/3923183, but after deleting the `.sock` file, nothing changed. None of the other solutions I've found were any help.

This is on my local machine, not a server, so I have no problem losing any data. I can easily replace it. I tried removing mongodb and reinstalling, but the problem persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what was the reason for reinstall? did mongod shutdown gracefully before reinstall?

Comment: I replaced the hard drive in my computer. As far as i know it shutdown correctly. I killed all the processes in terminal i had running and shut down the computer.

Comment: I did a time machine restore and I'm having a similar problem. Looking like starting fresh might be the only option right now... Luckily not production data and just me playing around with learning MongoDB but super annoying.

Answer (score 2):

you can just add new --dbpath in your config file, no need to reinstall mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your ulimit and give ownership to the db path of "mongodb" or "mongod" and restart your mongod it works for me.

Go to /etc/security/limit.conf and add the following lines and save the file and restart your machine to take effect.

```html
 * soft     nproc          200000
 * hard     nproc          200000
 * soft     nofile         200000
 * hard     nofile         200000
 * soft     memlock        2048
 * hard     memlock        2048
```

Answer (score -4):

So I was able to fix my problem by simply moving/deleting `/data/db` and and starting with an empty `/data/db` folder. Of course this removes all db data, so it's not really a solution to the problem and should only be done if you don't mind losing your data.