# Why does sudo service mongod start fail with linux ec2?

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Having some trouble configuring mongodb to Linux ec2 after following these directions https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx /]# sudo service mongod start
Error starting mongod. /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid exists.


[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx /]# sudo service mongod restart
Stopping mongod:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

I also tried `rm -f /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid` which now instantly fails.

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx /]# sudo service mongod start
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

I have a feeling it may be my `mongod.conf` and tried editing the dbPath and sysLogPath according to the docs.

```
# mongod.conf

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: "log/mongod.log"

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: "/data"
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
```

I am new to both AWS and deploying a db, and would appreciate suggestions!

Comment: check the file `log/mongod.log`

Comment: Of course! Thanks!!!

Comment: Check logs: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find a proper solution? need help

Answer (score 4):

After checking to log/mongod.log as @hjpotter92 suggested I found it was `***aborting after fassert() failure`

From the link below I ran the commands, which was successful.

`sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
rm -f /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo service mongod start`

[MongoDB Failing to Start - ***aborting after fassert() failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555603/mongodb-failing-to-start-aborting-after-fassert-)

Comment: ....working like charm..thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are using sudo while logged in as root .
Please recheck if this is is causing the issue .