# Mongodb start fail -- "aborting after fassert() failture"

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to docker-compose up on a DB and there seems to be an issue. It is returning a lot of jargon but stood out to me was `***aborting after fassert() failure`. I have searched for other similar issues and it says to do `mongod --repair` which looks like it returned a number of initandlisten messages. I ran `docker-compose up` and still return the logs below:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting transform-config-data_transform-config-data_1 ... done
Attaching to transform-config-data_transform-config-data_1
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=transform-config-data
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.17
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3d6953c361213c5bfab23e51ab274ce592edafe6
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.038+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.042+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.046+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=482M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.665+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31803) [1597292088:665129][1:0x7f5041e5aa40], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __wt_turtle_read, 336: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file read error: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found Raw: [1597292088:665129][1:0x7f5041e5aa40], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __wt_turtle_read, 336: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file read error: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.665+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] An unsupported journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback from version 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.665+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1597292088:665179][1:0x7f5041e5aa40], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1597292088:665179][1:0x7f5041e5aa40], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.665+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] An unsupported journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback from version 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.665+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 419
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.665+0000 F -        [initandlisten]
transform-config-data_1  |
transform-config-data_1  | ***aborting after fassert() failure
transform-config-data_1  |
transform-config-data_1  |
transform-config-data_1  | 2020-08-13T04:14:48.685+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
transform-config-data_1  |
transform-config-data_1  |  0x5620b1cac9f1 0x5620b1cabc09 0x5620b1cac0ed 0x7f504083e390 0x7f5040498428 0x7f504049a02a 0x5620b03bba8a 0x5620b0496f16 0x5620b05088d9 0x5620b0356cdc 0x5620b03570fc 0x5620b04cc446 0x5620b04ca5e4 0x5620b04aa340 0x5620b050719d 0x5620b0507775 0x5620b0507a0c 0x5620b05799a2 0x5620b0502d18 0x5620b04c9ade 0x5620b04c9bbb 0x5620b04a8e86 0x5620b0477cd9 0x5620b045ab28 0x5620b06621c5 0x5620b0435e2a 0x5620b0439642 0x5620b03bd759 0x7f5040483830 0x5620b0421969
transform-config-data_1  | ----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
transform-config-data_1  | {"backtrace":[{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"228C9F1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"228BC09"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"228C0ED"},{"b":"7F504082D000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7F5040463000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F5040463000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"99BA8A","s":"_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A76F16"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AE88D9"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"936CDC","s":"__wt_err_func"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"9370FC","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AAC446","s":"__wt_turtle_read"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AAA5E4","s":"__wt_metadata_search"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A8A340","s":"__wt_conn_dhandle_open"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AE719D","s":"__wt_session_get_dhandle"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AE7775","s":"__wt_session_get_dhandle"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AE7A0C","s":"__wt_session_get_btree_ckpt"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"B599A2","s":"__wt_curfile_open"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AE2D18"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AA9ADE","s":"__wt_metadata_cursor_open"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"AA9BBB","s":"__wt_metadata_cursor"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A88E86","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A57CD9","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mmbbbb"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A3AB28"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"C421C5","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A15E2A"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A19642","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"99D759","s":"main"},{"b":"7F5040463000","o":"20830","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"5620AFA20000","o":"A01969","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.6.17", "gitVersion" : "3d6953c361213c5bfab23e51ab274ce592edafe6", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.19.76-linuxkit", "version" : "#1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "5620AFA20000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E70A565FF1B0F5EB657AB205E08A2E68526CF314" }, { "b" : "7FFDACBDB000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B75FC78C250AED65F3D9722A8F5CBB07C9B34728" }, { "b" : "7F5041A23000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "50A923F8DAFECBCD969C8573116A38C18D0E24D5" }, { "b" : "7F50415DE000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "15FFEB43278726B025F020862BF51302822A40EC" }, { "b" : "7F5041375000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF69EA60EBE05F2DD689D2B26FC85A73E5FBC3A0" }, { "b" : "7F5041171000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "37BFC3D8F7E3B022DAC7943B1A5FACD40CEBF0AD" }, { "b" : "7F5040F69000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69143E8B39040C964D3958490535322675F15DD3" }, { "b" : "7F5040C60000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BAD67A84E56E73D031AE507261DA066B35949D34" }, { "b" : "7F5040A4A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7F504082D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B17C21299099640A6D863E423D99265824E7BB16" }, { "b" : "7F5040463000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1CA54A6E0D76188105B12E49FE6B8019BF08803A" }, { "b" : "7F5041C3E000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C0ADBAD6F9A33944F2B3567C078EC472A1DAE98E" } ] }}
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x5620b1cac9f1]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0x228BC09) [0x5620b1cabc09]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0x228C0ED) [0x5620b1cac0ed]
transform-config-data_1  |  libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f504083e390]
transform-config-data_1  |  libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f5040498428]
transform-config-data_1  |  libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7f504049a02a]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x5620b03bba8a]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0xA76F16) [0x5620b0496f16]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0xAE88D9) [0x5620b05088d9]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_err_func+0x90) [0x5620b0356cdc]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_panic+0x3F) [0x5620b03570fc]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_turtle_read+0x356) [0x5620b04cc446]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_metadata_search+0x1C4) [0x5620b04ca5e4]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_conn_dhandle_open+0xA0) [0x5620b04aa340]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_session_get_dhandle+0xED) [0x5620b050719d]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_session_get_dhandle+0x6C5) [0x5620b0507775]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_session_get_btree_ckpt+0x14C) [0x5620b0507a0c]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_curfile_open+0x52) [0x5620b05799a2]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0xAE2D18) [0x5620b0502d18]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_metadata_cursor_open+0x6E) [0x5620b04c9ade]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(__wt_metadata_cursor+0x4B) [0x5620b04c9bbb]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x1B66) [0x5620b04a8e86]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mmbbbb+0x8C9) [0x5620b0477cd9]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0xA3AB28) [0x5620b045ab28]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x275) [0x5620b06621c5]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(+0xA15E2A) [0x5620b0435e2a]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x872) [0x5620b0439642]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(main+0x9) [0x5620b03bd759]
transform-config-data_1  |  libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF0) [0x7f5040483830]
transform-config-data_1  |  mongod(_start+0x29) [0x5620b0421969]
transform-config-data_1  | -----  END BACKTRACE  -----
transform-config-data_transform-config-data_1 exited with code 14
```

Anyone ever dealt with this before? I have tried this: [MongoDB Failing to Start - ***aborting after fassert() failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555603/mongodb-failing-to-start-aborting-after-fassert-failure)

And it looks like there isn't even a .sock file in my machine. Let alone it returns `bash: sudo: command not found`. I tried it on Git bash and Command Prompt (both running as Admin) and no luck!

Comment: Your data directory is corrupt.

Comment: Please share your compose file and the way you mount your data directory. It seems that you're on Windows, right?

Comment: @AliTou You're correct. The mongo version was not correct in the docker-compose.yml file. I already pasted my solution to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay guys, the solution is was that I had to make sure the mongo version is correct in the docker-compose.yml file. I changed it from 3.6 to 4.0. It ran perfectly fine from there.