# Mongod - Insufficient free space for journal files after being hacked

Tags: mongodb

I got hacked and my entire production database was deleted. Now when I try to start mongod, I get the error:

```
 Insufficient free space for journal files
 Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongo/journal or use --smallfiles
```

Im on an AWS EC2 instance and have lots of space. What can I try?

I checked /etc/mongod.conf and there is a setting there:

```
storage:
    dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
```

However, from the logs, mongod is looking in `/data/db`. When I then create `/data/db` I get the error above about insufficient space...

**EDIT**
Ran df -kh /var/lib/mongo which returns

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.5G  3.3G  58% /
```

**EDIT**

Ok i increased space, that helped but now Im getting yet another error:

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

I have tried the solutions here ['Failed to unlink socket file" error in MongoDB 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0). That is, deleting the file, changing the permissions, but everytime I start mongod, the file reappears and the same error. When I run ls -al on that file I see:

```
srwx------ 1 mongod mongod 0 Jun  1 18:09 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: Check mongodb logs in /var/log/mongodb

Comment: [Journal files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) are an important part of the database engine; you need to have enough space for them.

Comment: I actually do have lots of space. What happened was I got hacked and my ENTIRE production database deleted. I tried to secure the database and now Im getting this error...

Comment: What does `df -kh /var/lib/mongo` return?

Comment: @robertklep returning Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.5G  3.3G  58% /

Comment: @Mark there's 3.3G free on that partition, so it's too small. Check if `/data` or `/data/db` is not actually a symlink to `/var/`. Still though, the error you're getting explicitly mentions `/var/lib/mongo/journal`.

Comment: @robertklep so maybe not enough space there?

Comment: Yep, the needed 3379MB is 3.379G which is more than the 3.3G available.

Comment: @robertklep ill try increasing my disk space on the EC2 instance and will update question

Comment: I dont know how so much is suddenly used up and coincidental it should happen now after having the database hacked

Comment: What method did you use to increase the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing disk space on my EC2 instance solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem. Just curious. How did you get around the lock permission issue ?

Comment: @Veeram deleting /data/db/mongod.lock fixed it for me

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem, which appeared out of nowhere. On minute my web app was working, and then it stopped. Did your issue have to do with space or hacking?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, mine also randomly stopped working and it turned out to be a disk space issue. Start debugging by looking at the actual MongoDB log file. That pointed it out for me.