# mongod : Failed to unlink socket file

Tags: database, mongodb

I am trying to start mongod.
I run

```
sudo service mongod start
```

but I get:

> Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Unknown error
> Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp
> 685

Theres a question here but I have tried all solutions to no avail

Os: Ubuntu 16.04
When I run

```
ls -lsah /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

I see:

```
0 srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Jun 14 11:45 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Then I run

```sh
rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock 
sudo service mongod start
```

When I run

```
ls -lsah /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

again, I see:

```
0 srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Jun 14 11:45 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

When I run `mongod`, it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and noticed this old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290982/2683681.

You can use their command:

```
sudo chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

But if you're using root then you'd better be doing:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

My problem stemmed from the fact that root owned the socket.