# mongod command not working and not able to connect to local port

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell

I just installed MongoDB from [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).
Currently I am running Pop_OS 20.04 LTS
I think MongoDB successfully installed

```
mongo --version

Output:
MongoDB shell version v5.0.2
```

After ensuring proper MongoDB version I started running:

```
mongod
```

**Output:**

{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.824+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.824+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.825+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.825+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.826+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.826+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.826+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":17565,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"deepak"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.2","gitVersion":"6d9ec525e78465dcecadcff99cce953d380fedc8","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Pop","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":960}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-26T09:35:44.827+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

[Output of above command command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE3dk.jpg)
I can't find similar error any where. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Failed to unlink socket file" error in MongoDB 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266