# Error "mongod dead but pid file exists"

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to start mongodb when I execute "/etc/init.d/mongod status
" I got message "mongod dead but pid file exists" i am new to mongodb Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

To get more info on why `mongod` is not starting successfully, you can check the mongodb log file for any errors. On CentOS, this file is most likely in `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`.

When this occurred for us once, it pointed to a permissions issue:

```
ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:13 Permission denied for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

This error can be resolved by setting the correct permissions on the `/tmp` directory, which is already answered in this Stackoverflow question: [MongoDB - Permission denied for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479384/mongodb-permission-denied-for-socket-tmp-mongodb-27017-sock)

Hope that helps!