# Unable to run mongodb in Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: node.js, mongodb, osx-elcapitan

Unable to run `mongodb` in `macOS ElCapitan`. When try to run `mongodb` after installing the `mongodb` using brew. I look in to the folder `/temp` but there is no such file as `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`?

Some one please give me a solution

I got error message like this when i try to run

> E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:1 Operation not permitted for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
>
> E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.

Answer (score 0):

Hum you say you looked into folder `/temp`, but it's folder `/tmp`. If it's not a typo, you can try running `sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` to remove this file.

Also check you have free disk space for running Mongo and your user [has permission to write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479630/6061078) into `/tmp` folder.

As a last resource you can run mongod as root: `sudo mongod`

Comment: Sorry its my bad , it's actually /tmp folder . But there was no "mongodb-27017.sock "  file found in that folder . I checked with the command "sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock" . But it says there is no such file in /tmp folder. @andresk