# [Error]MongoDB not starting

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to start mongodb it returns me this error, i already tried to repair mongo reinstall using brew uninstalling and installing again and nothing happens.

This problem occurred after Mac OS High Sierra Update.

Here's the error:

```
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11915 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Luizs-MacBook-Pro.local
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.9
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-09-27T20:55:54.834-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-09-27T20:55:54.835-0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed No such file or directory for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-09-27T20:55:54.836-0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-09-27T20:55:54.836-0300 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
2017-09-27T20:55:54.836-0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-09-27T20:55:54.836-0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-09-27T20:55:54.836-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-09-27T20:55:54.836-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

What i already tried:

`mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair`

`rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

`rm -rf /data/db`

Comment: check the permissions on the /tmp folder, I've seen this before with other programs and that's almost always the cause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Permission denied for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479384/mongodb-permission-denied-for-socket-tmp-mongodb-27017-sock)

Comment: I changed the permissions and still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

1: `sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db`

Replace `/data/db` by your `mongodb location` same as :

`sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

---

2: Check Port Status

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 27017

netstat -an |grep 27017
```

---

3: Kill ID

```
sudo killall mongod
sudo killall -15 mongod
sudo kill < Process ID >
```

Comment: Hey, I used this and it works like a charm. Would it be possible for you to give a brief explanation on what these commands do? I am new to the Mac world. Thanks.